# Binding a type with `Proxy s` vs binding a type with forall

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

in the following example, it is not clear to me why `toto` would fail, while `tata` would work.

Are there any explanation to this ?

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE  TypeFamilies, KindSignatures, FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables , GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses, RankNTypes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, UnicodeSyntax, DataKinds              #-}

import Data.Proxy

data KNat where
class ReflectNum (s :: KNat) where

toto ∷ (∀ (s :: KNat). ReflectNum s ⇒ Int) → Int
toto k = toto k

tata ∷ (∀ (s :: KNat). ReflectNum s ⇒ Proxy s -> Int) → Int
tata k = tata (\(p :: Proxy s) -> k p)
```

The error being

```
SO.hs:14:15: error:
    • Could not deduce (ReflectNum s0) arising from a use of ‘k’
      from the context: ReflectNum s
        bound by a type expected by the context:
                   forall (s :: KNat). ReflectNum s => Int
        at SO.hs:14:10-15
      The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
    • In the first argument of ‘toto’, namely ‘k’
      In the expression: toto k
      In an equation for ‘toto’: toto k = toto k
   |
14 | toto k = toto k
   |               ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation of GHC’s implementation of visible type application. Specifically, `Proxy` is sometimes still necessary in order to allow the argument to a higher-rank function (such as your `toto` function) to access a type variable.

There is a GHC proposal to add a solution to this problem, in the form of [type variable bindings in lambda-expressions](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/155). Using the syntax from the proposal, your `toto` function could be written as

```
toto k = toto (\@s -> k @s)
```

to locally bind the `s` variable. Sadly, this proposal has not yet been implemented.

In the meantime, for higher-rank functions like these, I think you just have to use `Proxy`. Sorry.

Comment: Great ! thank you for the reference, let's hope that make it through